# Iterating a vector from end to somewhere (not begin)

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm trying to iterate over a `std::vector` using `rbegin()` and an iterator coming from a `std::find_if()`. Of course `iterator` and `reverse_iterator` are not compatible. How can I do it ?

```
auto my_it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
    // irrelevant lambda
});

for (auto rit = vec.rbegin(); rit != my_it; ++rit)   // doesn't compile, iterators not compatible
{
    // do something
}
```

There are plenty of question on how to iterate from `rbegin()` to `rend()`, but I can't find anything for when I want to stop before `rend()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    auto it = std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), 5 );

    if ( it != v.end() )
    {        
        std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator last( it );

        for ( auto first = v.rbegin(); first != last; ++first ) std::cout << *first << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }       
}
```

The program output is

```
9 8 7 6 5
```

If you do not want to include the found iterator in the range then you can write

```
std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator last( ++it );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/reverse_iterator) function of `std::reverse_iterator` to access the underlying "normal" iterator:

```
for (auto rit = vec.rbegin(); 
     rit != std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator(my_it); 
     ++rit) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but Vlad's solution is more generic.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert either type of iterator to the other. As WhozCraig already suggested, you could just run your algorithm with rbegin() and rend().

If that is not an option, you can get the [base iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base):

```
auto my_it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [...]);

for (auto rit = vec.rbegin(); rit.base() - 1 != my_it; ++rit)
{
    // do something
}
```